# indescribable behavior of curly brackets

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

This is my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

            $("button").click(function() {

    $("#left").css({"border" : "red 2px solid , "color" : "red"});

                });
        });
```

It looks like some kind of a bug to me, cuz first curly bracket doesn't match its pair (which should be closing the code). Because of that all other curly brackets match mistakenly. 
[Screenshot should tell more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chW9l.png)
I tried rewriting this code and it worked properly. But i just want to know what is wrong with this one, cause i feel helpless trying to find an error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `"` character after `"red 2px solid`. Add that in and it'll be fine.